# Android: save ActivityInfo for the next app-launch

Tags: android

I have a list of ActivityInfo's. Each of this ActiityInfo represents an installed app on the device. The user can select a few items of the list and i want to save these items for the next launch of the activity. How do i do that? I know SharedPreferences, but they are for strings and int, aren't they?

```
List<ActivityInfo> apps = new ArrayList<ActivityInfo>();
ActivityInfo infoToSave = (ActivityInfo) apps.get(position);
```

EDIT: The question was how to turn infoToSave into a String which can be saved for further app-launches. Here is the solution:

```
ComponentName name = new ComponentName(infoToSave.packageName, infoToSave.name);
String nameS = name.flattenToString();
```

This string can be saved in SharedPreferences. However, thanks for all replies!

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, SharedPreferences are well utilized for storing small amounts of data of type key-value pairs (typically of strings). If your lists are serializable, you may then store your lists as SharedPreferences. onResume, of course, you must map your SharedPreferences back to List.

Alternatively, you may map the ActivityInfo to a new schema/table in the local SQLite Database. This approach is more scalable across multiple activities as you could then use contentResolvers to observe and read changes in ContentValues (you save) into the SQLite DB.

Read more about inserting and reading data to/from database at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

first the SharedPreferences isn't just for the string or int you can use Boolean or some other properties and you can use SQlite Database too

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html